# How to interact with REST end points that don't return a logical model or collection in a Backbone app

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

Using the Backbone Model and Collection utilities to interact with REST endpoints that return logical entities in your backend system makes sense. For example, endpoints like the following very logically map to models and collections:

```
GET /posts/:id > Model
GET /posts > Collection
PUT /posts/:id > Model
```

But what about endpoints that don't really map to a logical entity in your model? For example:

```
POST /user/login > ?
POST /user/validate-token > ?
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to force Backbone Models/Collection to work with endpoints like this. Writing some sort of service class using `$.ajax` or similar seems to be more appropriate. Trouble is we've spent quite a lot of time extending `Backbone.sync` to respond to particular error codes globally and don't want to duplicate that functionality in a service class too.

How are people interacting with REST endpoints that don't map to models and collections in their Backbone apps?

Comment: user combination of url attribute, fetch method, parse and 'data' parameter to fetch

Comment: So you're saying just hack Backbone models, even though the end points don't return models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to go ahead and answer my own question here. "mu is too short" got me on the right track in the comments above.

Since Backbone uses `$.ajax` to handle all its HTTP requests by default you can leverage `$.ajaxSetup()` and `$(document).ajaxError()` etc. to handle any app-wide AJAX setup and error responses. Then you're free to write your HTTP service classes using `$.ajax` too and leverage the same setup for both layers of server communication.